# React, object is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering another component in a form because it needs to change on a selected option. I am console logging all of the info needed in `AuxiliaryForm` and it's showing up as expected. No errors are occurring. It's just not rendering.

This is the main `CreatePage`

```
const axios = require("axios");

const { navState, navDispatch } = useContext(NavContext);

const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([{ option: "" }]);

const schema = yup.object().shape({
    sku: yup.string().required().min(8),
    name: yup.string().required().min(1),
    price: yup.string().required().min(1),
});

const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

function handleSelectChange(e) {
    // changeSchema();
    setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
}

console.log(selectedOption);
return (
    <form id="my-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSelectChange)}>
        <div id="product_form">
            {contentDef.inputs.map((input, key) => {
                return (
                    <div key={key} className="createContainer">
                        <div className="labelConatainer">
                            <label className="p-b2">{input.label}</label>
                        </div>

                        <div className="inputContainer">
                            <input
                                className="m-b2"
                                type="text"
                                name={input.name}
                                placeholder="ABC12345"
                                {...register(input.name, {
                                    required: true,
                                })}
                            />
                            <h3 className="error-msg">
                                {console.log(errors[input.name]?.message)}
                                {errors[input.name]?.message}
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>

        <div id="productType" className="productType">
            <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                <option>--TYPE--</option>
                <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                <option value="DVD Disc">DVD Disc</option>
                <option value="Book">Book</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            {selectedOption == "Furniture" ? (
                <AuxiliaryForm product={selectedOption} />) : ("")}
            {selectedOption == "Book" ? (
                <AuxiliaryForm product={selectedOption} />) : ("")}
            {selectedOption == "DVD Disc" ? (
                <AuxiliaryForm product={selectedOption} />) : ("")}
        </div>
    </form>
```

`AuxiliaryForm` looks like this:

```
// console.log(props);
let schema;
let content;
let infoMessage;

const schemaFurniture = yup.object().shape({
    height: yup.string().required().min(1),
    width: yup.string().required().min(1),
    length: yup.string().required().min(1),
});

const schemaBook = yup.object().shape({
    weight: yup.string().required().min(1),
});

const schemaDvd = yup.object().shape({
    size: yup.string().required().min(1),
});

const changeSchema = () => {
    switch (props.product) {
        case "Furniture":
            schema = schemaFurniture;
            content = contentFurniture;
            infoMessage =
                "Please enter Furnitures Height, Weight, and Length (in CM). Do not enter any letters.";
            break;

        case "DVD Disc":
            schema = schemaDvd;
            content = contentDvd;
            infoMessage =
                "Please enter DVD Discs size (in CM). Do not enter any letters.";
            break;

        case "Book":
            schema = schemaBook;
            content = contentBook;
            infoMessage =
                "Please enter the weight of the book (in KG). Do not enter any ers.";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
};

changeSchema();
console.log(schema, "<-schema", content, "<-content", infoMessage, "<-infoMessage"
);

const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

return (
    <>
        {content.inputs.map((input, key) => {
            console.log(input);
            <div key={key} className="createContainer" id="Furniture">
                <div className="labelConatainer">
                    <label className="p-b2">{input.label}</label>
                </div>

                <div className="inputContainer">
                    <input
                        className="m-b2"
                        type="text"
                        name={input.name}
                        placeholder="10"
                        {...register(input.name, {
                            required: true,
                        })}
                    />
                    <h3 className="error-msg">
                        {console.log(errors[input.name]?.message)}
                        {errors[input.name]?.message}
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="formDescription">
                    <h4>{infoMessage}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>;
        })}
    </>
);
```

And the console logs look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the `map` function inside `content.inputs.map((input, key) => {`.

Updated map function should be something like below

```
{content.inputs.map((input, key) => {
  console.log(input);
  return (
    <div key={key} className="createContainer" id="Furniture">
        <div className="labelConatainer">
            <label className="p-b2">{input.label}</label>
        </div>

        <div className="inputContainer">
            <input
                className="m-b2"
                type="text"
                name={input.name}
                placeholder="10"
                {...register(input.name, {
                    required: true,
                })}
            />
            <h3 className="error-msg">
                {console.log(errors[input.name]?.message)}
                {errors[input.name]?.message}
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div className="formDescription">
            <h4>{infoMessage}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about it.

Comment: @AleksandrsBarbins Glad I could help. If you use the `es6` syntax `(e.g. {[items].map(item => (
    <Row key={item.id}>
        {children}
    </Row>
))})` for map, you don't need to worry about the `return`.